# Does restoring from an iCloud backup enforce installation of the latest iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, restore

I accidentally deleted a lot of text messages on my iPhone 5 and would like to restore from iCloud by choosing "Erase all content and settings" and then restoring from a backup made last night.  However, my iPhone is running iOS 6 and I would not like to update to iOS 8.  If I restore my phone from the iCloud backup using "Erase all content and settings" will iOS 8 be installed or will it restore the iPhone with iOS 6 as it was last night?  I would try it out, but I would prefer to find out before rather than after...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Erase all content and settings keeps your current iOS. As long as you don't use an iCloud backup from a device with a newer iOS version you will be fine.

Comment: That is great news!  Are you sure that the upgrade is not forced?  My one hesitation is that this support page: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts4036 seems to suggest that you need the latest iOS version to restore from an iCloud backup (“making sure that your device is using the latest version of iOS”).  I just want to make sure that the upgrade won't be forced.

Comment: The only forced upgrade is when you are in recovery mode and iTunes doesn't have the version of iOS downloaded to match what you have. iTunes will _offer_ an upgrade but you are free to decline it in that case. Only if you have a stuck device and no download are you forced to upgrade